# Export Project from Eclipse As Folder

Tags: java, export

I have a game that I have finished and need to export now. I want people to be able to make mods for it, so therefore, I need a folder with all the classes that my game can find and run from that folder.

I know how to export it into an Archive Folder, but when you do that, you can't actually run it and play it.

I was thinking it could work like Minecraft does, where it creates a folder on your computer, that has the classes in it, and when you start up Minecraft, it finds this folder and uses it to run.

Answer (score 0):

You can export it as a Runnable Jar file
.With that you can run and play it , and when you open the jar with an archive manager you can see the classes.

In eclipse right click and select export ,
Under 'Java' there is an option for Runnable Jar. Select your Launch class and the export destination.

I hope this helped you.

Comment: It's hard to make changes to compiled java files (`.class` files in a  runnable jar) so game logic is hard to change. If you only want to change textures or sound files it'll work.

Comment: You can export the classes you want, modify them somehow and put them back overwritting the old ones. Will this not work?

Comment: The thing is, when you open the jar and make changes, it's not going to affect the original game jar. Is there a way to recompile the folder that contains the classes?